# django allauth with jinja2 templates

Tags: django-templates, jinja2, django-allauth, django-3.0

I would like to know if it is possible to use the django-allauth app with jinja2 templates instead of DTL templates.

There does not appear to be any clear information about this, or usable examples available. I am unsure if this is because its easy and therefore doesn't warrant its own explanation, or because its impossible.

I am aware of [this](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/issues/1784) feature request, but it is 3 years old.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is. You'll need to use crispy forms in jinja templates though.